# Are malicious crawling bots a form of application layer DoS?

Tags: denial-of-service, bot, web-crawler

I would assume that if someone is daily crawling a website in a way which is heavily laborious on the server it may overkill that server.

Are malicious crawling bots a form of application layer DoS?

Comment: a crawler shouldn't create any problem on a web server if is properly dimension in terms of capacity (network, cpu, and so on) , however is recommended to block them because some of them search for vulnerabilities that are use later for attack the system.

Comment: *"this person wants to overkill our server"* - If the primary target is to stress the server than there are likely more effective ways to do this. Thus unlikely that this is their actual goal. Also, your question is a) making an (in my opinion wrong) assumption and ask if it is true and b) assume that this assumption is true w/o waiting for feedback and then ask how to deal with it. If a) is already wrong than b) makes no sense to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are malicious crawling bots a form of application layer DoS?

While they can result in a denial of service they are usually not intended as a denial of service attack and therefore I would not call these DoS attacks. They are instead intended to grab information with high speed. The failure of the server to cope with this high speed information retrieval is an unintended side effect. It not only is unwanted by the server operator but also by the crawler operator, since it impacts their goal to grab information.

Comment: `also by the crawler operator, since it impacts their goal to grab information.` the crawler operator runs the evil crawler but also suffers from its own action?

Comment: @sosoalter: As I said, the goal for the crawler is to collect information. If the site cannot serve the information since its overloaded, than the goal for the crawling is negatively affected.